# Why do I need to assign false to each element in BFS but not in DFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Function definitions are :

```
// DFS algorithm
void Graph::DFS(int current) {


    visited[current] = true;
    cout<<current << " ";
        

    for (int u : adjLists[current])
        if (!visited[u])
            DFS(u);

}

// BFS algorithm

void Graph::BFS(void){
    
    for(int i=0;i<numVertices;++i)
        visited[i] = false;
        
    list<int> q;
    q.push_back(0);
    visited[0] = true;
    
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        cout<< u << "  ";
        
        for( int i : adjLists[u])
            if(!visited[i]){
                q.push_back(i);
                visited[i] = true;
            }   
    }
}
```

DFS is working fine without using for loop to assign each element of visited array equal to `false` but BFS is not. Why?
Whole program code is - https://hastebin.com/ojuyogexof.cpp

Comment: Sounds like [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to me. Try calling BFS first, and then see if DFS works. Sometimes bad programs work even though they are bad. This is how undefined behaviour can work.

Comment: @john yes you are right , calling BFS first DFS is not working fine. So I need to use for loop for both functions ( but how can I because DFS is recursive )?

Comment: You need to have a function which starts the depth first search by setting the visited array to false and then calling your recursive function.

Comment: @john fine everything sorted out now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visited array never got initialised to `fasle` before calling the `DFS()` and that is why the output for the `DFS()` is only single node (starting node), i.e., **2**.

**Output for the entire code (without initialising visited array to false):**

```
DFS 
2 
BFS
0  2  1  3
```

**SUGGESTION:** Define a function `init()` function and call it before performing `DFS()` or `BFS()`:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Graph {
    int numVertices;
    list<int> *adjLists;
    bool *visited;

    public:
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int src, int dest);
    void DFS(int vertex);
    void BFS(void);
    void init();
};

// Initialize graph
Graph::Graph(int vertices) {
    numVertices = vertices;
    adjLists = new list<int>[vertices];
    visited = new bool[vertices];
    for(int i=0;i<numVertices;++i){
        visited[i] = false;
    }
}

void Graph::init() {
    for(int i=0;i<numVertices;++i)
        visited[i] = false;
}

// Add edges
void Graph::addEdge(int src, int dest) {
    adjLists[src].push_front(dest);
    adjLists[dest].push_front(src);
}

// DFS algorithm
void Graph::DFS(int current) {
        
    visited[current] = true;
    cout<<current << " ";
        
    for (int u : adjLists[current])
        if (!visited[u])
            DFS(u);

}

// BFS algorithm

void Graph::BFS(void){
    
    list<int> q;
    q.push_back(0);
    visited[0] = true;
    
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        cout<< u << "  ";
        
        for( int i : adjLists[u])
            if(!visited[i]){
                q.push_back(i);
                visited[i] = true;
            }    
    }
}

int main() {
    
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);


    g.init();
    int start_node = 2 ;
    cout<<"DFS \n";
    g.DFS(start_node) ;

    g.init();
    cout<<endl<<"BFS"<<endl;
    g.BFS();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
DFS 
2 3 1 0 
BFS
0  2  1  3
```